# SyntaxError: only named arguments may follow *expression on nn.Sequential()

Tags: python-2.7, pytorch

```
def forward(self, x):
    x = x.view(-1)
    fwd = nn.Sequential(self.linear_1, *self.middle, self.output)
    return fwd(x)
```

It works python3 but not python2.7. The error is:

> fwd = nn.Sequential(self.linear_1, *self.middle, self.output)
>   SyntaxError: only named arguments may follow *expression
>   )

What can I convert this code to work on python2.7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following syntax:

```
fwd = nn.Sequential(self.linear_1, *(self.middle + [self.output]))
```

This is assuming that `self.middle` is a list while `self.output` is an item (of class `nn.Module`).

The trick here is to combine `self.middle` and `self.output` in a single list and pass that to the `nn.Sequential` method.